# Open Graph - Custom Action & Object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to implement the Open Graph custom action and object.

I'm using this tutorial as a reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Things seem to work fine, and I'm able to use the curl command to post an action on my timeline.
However, when trying to do it from the site, the popup that request for permission doesn't have the open graph action request, even though I request for publish_actions permission.

What am I missing? Do I have to publish the action first before it will show up on the referral dialog? Note that under the app setting, if I go to Auth Dialog > advanced and do "Preview Referral Dialog", the popup dialog looks correct.

[image]

Comment: No, I have not submitted my action yet. But I am the admin. Would it only work once I submit? Also I tried submitting but I can't, it says I need to at least post an action, which is the thing I haven't been able to do. Or do I use curl to do the first post and submit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Admin or Developer of the application, you will be able to request permission to publish_actions before the action is approved. Try using the API Explorer tool to test the request you are making from the website: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Are you removing the application before trying to test the action from your site? If you have already approved the app and the requested permission, you won't see the Dialog box again.

Post up the code you are using to request the publish_actions permission. Also, make sure 'Enhanced Auth Dialog' is enabled from the 'Advanced' Settings for your App.